# Go back from Storyboards to XIB

Tags: ios, xib, storyboard

Not knowing that Storyboards are iOS5 only I created project that could be run even on iOS 2.0, but now I can't compile it with target lower than iOS5. Is there an easy way to go back to simple XIB file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's an automatic way to downgrade. Create new xib files for each view controller that needs them and link their view with the appropriate .h file. You should be able to copy and paste your whole UIView container view from storyboard to an xib though so it's really not that bad.

EDIT:
Also, I recently had to do this myself and a few things that weren't immediately obvious to me were that I also had to create a MainWindow.xib file, change your application plist, main.m, and my app delegate. Was definitely more complex than I expected but can confirm it can be done.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to avoid it but it seems to be the only solution. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain the process in more detail?

Comment: @Keller I also wouldn't mind more clarification. Google is not helping me too much here other than some unclear answers on Stack Overflow. Will up vote.